# Edit Task directly from Home Page

Tags: tasks, home-page-component, edit

Is it possible / was it ever possible to edit the due date of tasks in the "My Tasks" home screen component without leaving the page?

One of our users beleives that in the past, it opened the record edit window on the homepage - but now they have to click into the task and edit the due date.

Is there a way to inline edit tasks from this component? Has the functionality changed?

[image: my task]

Comment: I didn't find a way based on my recent research. You can have a look at all relevant hyperlink pages in this article: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000316467&type=1&mode=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, neither in the past  nor now. We can't edit the due date of tasks in the "My Tasks" home screen component without leaving the page.

Verify with the user if he/she is thinking of clicking the 'View All' link on the My Tasks component , then selecting the list view to do inline editing for 'Due Date'